# Update programmatically Group Audience

Tags: nodes, organic-groups

I have made a hook_node_insert which when I create a group content of type A, it create a node group. I want to associate my type A with the created group with the field audience.
I have changed the field group audience like that

```
$nodeA->group_audience = array(
    LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
        '0' => array(
            'gid' => $group->gid,
        ),
    ),
);
```

But it doesn't save the data into the database. I have tested with node_save but I have the error that primary key nid is duplicated.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're changing the `$node` inside a `node_save()` or something, your changes won't make it into the database unless you add a `node_save()` after the change to `$node`.